# HP Elitebook does not recognize USB keyboard if Logitech Unifying receiver (for mouse) is plugged in

Tags: hp-elitebook, logitech-unifying-receiver, usb-keyboard

My HP Elitebook 8470p normally is used with a Logitech K120 USB keyboard (just a standard USB keyboard). As I recently bought a new mouse (Logitech Performance MX) that has a unifying receiver, the laptop does not recognize the USB keyboard anymore, as soon as I boot with the unifying receiver plugged in.

If I plug the receiver in after booting, the keyboard continues to work. But always unplugging it, booting, plugging it is no solution to make it work.

Any ideas?